# Accessing Array Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, multidimensional-array

I want to access the `request_uuid` from my **jquery** post, but whatever I try doesn't work. I keep getting this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'request_uuid' of undefined

This is my array:

```
Array(
[status] => 201
[response] => Array
    (
        [api_id] => 6562c748-0366-11e5-84ff-22000ac89064
        [message] => call fired
        [request_uuid] => efa98dad-8869-4b72-ad99-a149f914bda5
    ))
```

I am trying to access it like this:

```
console.log(data.response['request_uuid']);
```

How should I access it to get the `request_uuid`?

Comment: try with this console.log(data.response[0]['request_uuid']);

Comment: `console.log(data[response]['request_uuid']);`

Comment: sorry non of the above works! i keep getting an error message

Comment: ok then as Leo answered if both is array then use console.log(data[0].response[0]['request_uuid']);   . or update your answer with proper array as answered

Answer (score 1):

If your data is an array and your response also, you must to parse the first child(0), before that:

[] = Array():

```
var data = [{
    'status': 201,
    'response': [{
        'api_id': "6562c748-0366-11e5-84ff-22000ac89064",
        'message': "call fired",
        'request_uuid': "efa98dad-8869-4b72-ad99-a149f914bda5"
    }]
}];

console.log(data[0].response[0]['request_uuid']);
```

Comment: @jhondano  proper array means . array in proper javascript format as leo mentioned in answer :)

Comment: @jhondano because your server side sends an array, it means you can have more than one data object, like data[0], data[1] and so on. Same for your response object, like response[0], response[1]. A good way to understand it, is calling console.log(data). Open it on Chrome Dev Tools(or similar) and You'll see when it's an array, and when it's a property of a object

Comment: yes thanks for your reply... actually thats exactly what am doing the array posted above is comming from console.log(data). I am confused how can i get my array in proper jquery format?

Comment: @jhondano It's actually a Javascript Object which in your case, the serverside responds as an array. Try remember, every time you read Array(), you can have 1 or more, so you must to refer as an array. Maybe this theory will help you https://spring.io/understanding/JSON